# A simple classical probability theory misunderstanding

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus, probability-theory, probability-distributions

It has been a long time since I learn classical probability theory in high school. Can anybody explain to me what I am doing wrong here?

Suppose I have a well-shuffled stack of $11$ cards that spell the word MISSISSIPPI. Sample space for the experiment of blindly picking the top card of this deck is $$\Omega=\{M, I, S, P\}.$$ Am I correct?
When the event $A$ is getting "$P$", its probability is $$P(A)=\dfrac{n_A}{n_S},$$ and $n_A=1$ and $n_S=4.$ But shouldn't the probability be $\dfrac{2}{11}$?

Comment: No, those are the codomain of a random variable that represents a draw. If you want to think of the probability distribution on the sample space as being uniform then you will need to have more elements in the space and then map them to those four values. For example you can have $\Omega$ contain abstract elements $\omega_1,\dots,\omega_{11}$ and then a random variable $X$ that sends $\omega_i$ to the $i$th letter in the word MISSISSIPPI.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use $S$ as both the name for the sample space; and the designation of the occurrence of picking a letter $S$.

Comment: @Ian: Thank you for your comment. Which of my questions were being answered with "No"? Also, do you care to turn your comment to an answer?

Comment: @paw88789: Suggestion accepted :)

Comment: Please read my answer [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/19548/372).

Comment: @ryang: Thank you for directing me there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can look at this in two ways:

1. The sample space is $ \{ M, I, S, S, I, S, S, I, P, P, I \} $ and the simple events of the sample space all have equal probabilities. Using $ P(A) = \dfrac{n_A}{n_S} $ we have $ P(A) = \dfrac{2}{11} $.
2. The sample space is $ \{ M , I , S, P \} $ but the simple events of the sample space do not have equal probabilities. This means that we must asign probabilities to all four $ \{M\}, \{I\}, \{S\} , \{P\} $. We can actually assign any numbers we want provided they are non-negative and add up to 1. Of course the only assignment that corresponds to the problem you are describing is $ P(\{M\}) = \frac{1}{11}, ~P(\{I\})=\frac{4}{11}, ~P(\{S\})=\frac{4}{11} , P(\{P\})=\frac{2}{11} $.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear explanation. If I recall correctly, sample space is the set of all possible outcomes. So, 2. would be the better explanation?

Comment: For 1., it can be seen as you mark each card with both letter and index, for example $P_{1}$, $P_{2}$, hence you have 11 different cards (11 different outcomes). And the event $A$ can be explicitly rewritten as the card you pick is either $P_{1}$ or $P_{2}$.